# Open source authenticator for Linux

Tags: linux, two-factor-authentication

Is there an open source Authenticator desktop application (not browser extension) for Linux similar to [WinAuth](https://github.com/winauth/winauth) for Windows?

[image]

This application allows you to register two-factor authentication configurations such that it will generate various types of OTP. WinAuth in particular supports time-based and counter-based OTP.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/)** includes the very same feature and lets you set up OTP if you know the seed (aka "secret code"):

[image] [image]
<sup>(click screenshots for larger variants)</sup>

Details can be found i [its manual](https://keepassxc.org/). As the sreenshots show, the application works cross-platform (I'm using it with Linux on my personal machine as well as on the Windows machine I have to use at work).